# Any more ways I could try to get my out-of-space Btrfs data-raid6 mdata-raid1c4 volume operational again?

Tags: btrfs

The volume consists of 9 disks total, one of them has plenty of space (the new one I had added shortly before running out of space), one with only 289 MiB of free metadata space, and all the others with just 1 MiB metadata space left: https://pastebin.com/CXfe0X8i

I'm on kernel 6.3.6, but the issue was created many months ago, by moving some data back on the drive while it was rebalancing, reasoning it was fine since I moved much less data back on the volume than I moved off of it earlier.

The volume mounts fine with option skip_balance, but every further operation I've tried causes it to go read-only:

`sudo mount /dev/sda -o subvol=@,skip_balance,noatime /run/media/damian101/RAID6/ && sudo btrfs balance cancel /run/media/damian101/RAID6/`

`sudo mount /dev/sda -o subvol=@,skip_balance,noatime /run/media/damian101/RAID6/ && sync -f /run/media/damian101/RAID6 && rm '/run/media/damian101/RAID6/<largefile>'`

`sudo mount /dev/sda -o subvol=@,skip_balance,noatime /run/media/damian101/RAID6/ && sudo btrfs device add /dev/sdl1 /dev/sdl2 /dev/sdl3 /run/media/damian101/RAID6/`

With the last command I tried to add enough new devices to have enough metadata space available to start balancing again, but this operation fails too.

Am I out of options, temporarily moving all data to other storage aside?

I sadly don't have any subvolumes on the volume I could delete, nor free space at the end of my Btrfs partitions.